# How do I write code using anaconda (mac)?

Tags: python, macos, anaconda

I'm not so much a novice as a new-born when it comes to anything more technical than setting up my email client. Teaching myself Python has been a steep learning curve to say the least.

Here's what I want to do:

**Import a list of from excel and run it through a code.**

Here's what I've done/tried:

**1)** Download & install `anaconda`

**2)** Used launcher to open `Spyder`

**3)** Try 100 different ways to install `xlrd` (or anything else) and fail. The common error is:

> name 'conda' is not defined

**4)** Used the `mac terminal` (accessed via the search spotlight) to go through all the dest drive documentation

I don't know if Spyder is the right platform to use for this, but it looked right. And I'm sure there's an easy solution, but I'm absolutely, hopelessly lost and would love some help and guidance. I have spent hours trying to figure it out!

Comment: What happens if you type Python at the command prompt?

Comment: If I type ```Python``` into the terminal I get: ```(root)Seans-Air-2:~ Seansmac$ Python
Python 2.7.11 |Anaconda 2.5.0 (x86_64)| (default, Dec  6 2015, 18:57:58) 
[GCC 4.2.1 (Apple Inc. build 5577)] on darwin
Type "help", "copyright", "credits" or "license" for more information.
Anaconda is brought to you by Continuum Analytics.
Please check out: http://continuum.io/thanks and https://anaconda.org```.       If I type it in the ipython console in Spyder I get: ```NameError: name 'Python' is not defined```

Comment: Ok, so the error is: 'name Python not defined' rather than 'name Conda not defined' as in your original post. Sorry, beats me, at this moment...

Comment: I think that was a typo actually. I've since realised (after a pretty painful process) that my question didn't really make sense. But thanks anyway!